# How to add days in querying date? laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can we add days in the date that we're querying using laravel eloquent?

Something like this:

```
Post::where('created_at + 7 days', now()->toDateTimeString())
    ->where('created_at', '<', now()->toDateTimeString())
    ->get();
```

My logic is like this one

> today >= created_at && today <= created_at + 4

Is there some correct syntax to achieve this one?

Comment: Today always will be grather than created_at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to compare from date time is using the calculated Carbon like below:

```
Post::where('created_at', '>=', now()->addDays(4)->toDateTimeString()
    ->get();
```

It will display only posts which have created_at greater than 4 days from today.

For date range filter, you can use **between** scope like:

```
$startDate = now()->subDays(4)->toDateString();
$endDate = now()->toDateString();

$filteredPosts = Post::whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();
```

For more information about filter, you could visit [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

Comment: it returns wrong data sir. I think that is because, the value of `created_at` should be added by 4 days not `today`

Comment: Yes, is wrong because you're adding 4 days in Today, should be substracted

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whereDate` method:

```php
Post::whereDate('created_at', 'like', now()->subDays(4))->get();
```

or

```php
Post::whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(4))->get();
```

Comment: I added the full logic sir in the description, i forgot it should be between.