# Can you manipulate a database column date in Laravel, and then use a `whereDate()` clause, without using DB::raw?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

### Question:

Can you manipulate a database column date in Laravel, and then use a `whereDate()` clause on the manipulated date? (using the Query Builder)

I know I can do it using `DB::raw` with SQL functions but I would like to know of a method without using `DB::raw`, like this I can utilize `Carbon` or other php and Laravel functionality.

### Code:

`->whereDate('sub_weekdays(end_of_month(add_month(date_column)), 10))', '>', today()`

I want to run these carbon functions on the database `date_column` and then do the  `'>', today()` check.

### Research:

There are numerous `whereDate` and `whereRaw` questions on stackoverflow, but none that I came across seem to address this issue.
The Laravel docs also don't discuss how to do this, or if it's possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67715288/how-to-add-days-in-querying-date-laravel/67715368#67715368

Comment: @DanielMesa Thank you. I have used the method in the linked questions in the past, but here I need a more specific manipulation, that I don't think I can do the inverse for on `today()`. (I edited the questions to include the specific manipulation needed).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it totally `DB::raw()` style, i would believe the most pragmatic approach, would to use `DB::raw()` in the column only. You keep the main `QueryBuilder` calls, while achieving what you want. The carbon idea you have is not feasible, as you want the query approach, all modifications has to done in `SQL`.

```
->whereDate(DB::RAW('LAST_DAY(date_column)'), now())
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was referring to as using DB::RAW. What do you mean by 'it should be done in SQL only'?

Comment: You wanted to get Carbon logic in the query builder, but as all modifications to the date has to be done In SQL that is not feasible.

Comment: You could wrap this logic in a class and solve it your self. Something like ->whereDate((string) SqlDate::lastDay('date_column'), now()) would be possible, but thats your own code not laravel